# linear transformation about the z axis

Tags: linear-algebra

You want to add $(1,2,3)$ to every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then rotate about the $z$ axis counterclockwise through an angle of $30$ degrees. Find what happens to the point $(1,1,1)$

I know how to rotate about the $z$ axis with the $\cos(\theta)\, ...\, -\sin(\theta)$ matrix but I don't know how to approach this problem

Comment: Try it just one step at a time. First add $(1,2,3)$ and see what you get. _Then_ rotate.

Comment: add (1,2,3) to what? I don't understand the matrix that i am adding it to

Comment: Translate  $(1,1,1)$ by adding $(1,2,3)$ to it -- *then* rotate the resulting point using the matrix of the rotation.

Comment: I don't see anything about a matrix, just a question about what happens to one point.

Comment: The composition of a nontrivial translation and a rotation is *not* a linear transformation -- it is an *affine* one: it is not of the form $X\to AX$, but of the form $X \to AX+b$.